# Webix - hiding menu items

Tags: javascript, menu, webix

Is it possible to make a menu item invisible via some action using Webix? Perhaps, by clicking on a button - any ideas?
For this case I made a snippet with basic implementation:
http://webix.com/snippet/29018dad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `hideItem` method to your button. Here's the example:

```
{ view:"button", ... 
  click:function(id){
      $$("top_menu").hideItem(3);
  }
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/4675566e